# Searching on photos containing multiple faces

Tags: amazon-web-services, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

I have more than 2,000 photos from running competitions. Several to several dozen faces are visible in each of the photos. I want to find photos in which it is me or any of my few friends.

I have several photos of each of the people I am looking for. So I [created a collection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/create-collection-procedure.html) with these photos (faces). In this collection, I [created users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/create-user.html) and [associated faces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/associate-faces.html) of myself and friends to them. Later on, I wanted to check if any user from the collection was in each of the photos. Unfortunately [SearchUsersByImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/search-users-by-image.html) only checks the largest face from a given photo. So it won't work the way I wanted it to.

I'm planning to create a big collection containing the faces of all the people in those 2000 photos. When adding faces to the collection, I will specify the file name of the photo in ExternalImageId. I will then use the photos (my own and my friends') to [search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/search-face-with-image-procedure.html) if that face is in the collection. Based on the faces found from the ExternalImageId, I will read which photos they appear in.

Is this a good idea? How should I approach this to get the desired result and not incur excessive costs?

Comment: CompareFaces will compare a face in a source image with each of the 100 largest faces detected in a target image. So if you have stored all your friends' faces individually as images then you can search for each of them one-by-one in a given running competition photo. I'm not aware of a way to do this for multiple source face images in a single API call however.

Comment: @jarmod Won't this approach come out many times more expensive than what I am planning — $0.001 (CompareFaces) * 2000 (photos) * 5 (people searched for) = $10?  
What I am planning seems to cost $0.001 (IndexFaces) * 2000 (photos) + $0.001 (SearchFacesbyImage) * 5 (people searched for) + $0.00001 (Face Vector Storage) * 2000 (photos) * 20 (average faces per photo) / 30 (1 day) = $2.02

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I wasn't really considering the cost of the CompareFacs approach. I'm not aware of better approaches that use Rekognition.